# VueJs2- Error occured while deploying vuejs app through tomcat

Tags: tomcat, vuejs2

I have deployed vuejs2 app to tomcat server. As a result of "npm run build", dist folder has been created. I copied the ***"static folder***" and ***"index.html file"*** inside the Tomcat's webapps folder [IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYPdQ.png). When I run the server, UI becomes blank and error occured [ERROR1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxg0l.png). Hence I have changed the "src path" inside the "index.html" file i.e. **I have removed all the "/" slashes before the word "static".**

Now my **index.html** file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<meta name=viewport
    content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>CoreUI - Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=static/img/favicon.png>
<link href=static/css/app.a6a6629a4b2d2029e98d4ff760232674.css
    rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body
    class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
    <div id=app></div>
    <script type=text/javascript
        src=static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript
        src=static/js/vendor.f41d9b8e13cff17b9752.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=static/js/app.3ca9e311e8d1cae856ab.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After the path changes UI appeared. But the given icons in the UI (in the login page and left menu's icon) are not loaded properly and showing error in the console [ERROR2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNDiY.png) , [ERROR4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCHUy.png). I don't know the reason for this error. Kindly help me to load icons without any error.

Thanks in advance

**Static folder structure :**
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOpKP.png)

Comment: Looks like the required font files are missing from the `static` directory.

Comment: No, it's there. "Fonts" folder is present inside the static folder

Comment: Is it `Fonts` or `fonts`? Because it is case-sensitive.

Comment: "fonts". I can add the image for ur reference. But I don't know how to add inage inside "comment" area

Comment: Ok just eliminating that as possibility. It may be helpful to paste screenshot of file structure showing font files in your original question.

Comment: I have added the image inside the question folder.

Comment: That all seems correct at first glance. I'm assuming there is some sort of a deploy process happening and not serving that `dist` folder directly. I'd just verify that all files are being deployed/copied correctly.